# Unusual conversion from html to json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a POC to deliver which entitle to convert html content into a json file. This means the json file needs to be in a specific format which I can't figure out how to display it. I have not working out how to format the nodeChild elements in the format requested, so I need help on this matter.

This is the HTML content:

```
<body>
    <style>
        .myclass{padding-top:50px; left:0;}
    </style>

    <div id="maincontent">
      <div id="myid">
          <p class="myclass">
              This is a paragraph
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

And this is the .json format I need to be expelled out from the HTML content:

"t" stands for "type:, "s" stands for "style" and "h" stands for "html"

```
[
{
    "t": "s",
    "s": ".myclass{padding-top:50px; left:0;}"
},
{
    "t": "h",
    "h": "<div id='myid'><p class='myclass'>This is a paragraph</p></div>"
}]
```

At the moment the file generated looks like this. But I need to place all the content in an unique line and not separated.

```
{
            "t": "DIV",
            "content": [{
                "t": "DIV",
                "content": ["This is a paragraph"],
                "s": {
                    "class": "myclass"
                }
            }],
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no limitations on where <style> can be used - what's expected to happen if a <style> was, for example, inside that paragraph?

Comment: I second the above comment. I don't know what your end goal is, but wouldn't it make it easier if you used an actual JSON representation of the DOM nodes and their children, like this library does? [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser)

Comment: If the style was inside the paragraph would be posted inside the "h" iniline with the paragraph. At the moment I can save a .json file, but the format is not the expected as the childNodes are all separated by tags and content.

Comment: Ok. Also, do you do this in a browser, or server-side with NodeJS? That's a big difference. If it's in the browser, you can take advantage of it to traverse the DOM, otherwise, you'll want to use a DOM parsing library, since [Regex is not the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I'm doing with NodeJS, mapping the DOM elements and parsing as a string and then pushing through a function that creates a list of childNodes and nodeValues. At the moment my file looks like this: {
                "t": "DIV",
                "content": [{
                    "t": "SPAN",
                    "content": ["Watch how it works"],
                    "s": {"class": "cta_l"
                     }],
                "s": {"id": "cta", "data-bind": "text:atomk_cta_1.Value"
                }}.   ------> I need to convert all in one type and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using the [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) library and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
// Don't forget to `npm i -S node-html-parser`
const HTMLParser = require("node-html-parser");

const root = HTMLParser.parse(
  `<!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
                <head> </head>
                <body>
                  <style>
                    .myclass {
                      padding-top: 50px;
                      left: 0;
                    }
                  </style>

                  <script>
                    var name = 'world';
                    console.log('Hello ' + name);
                  </script>

                  <div id="maincontent">
                    <div id="myid">
                      <p class="myclass">
                        This is a paragraph
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </body>
              </html>`,
  {
    style: true, // Keep styles
    script: true // Keep scripts
  }
).querySelector("body");

// Clean up whitespace text nodes
root.removeWhitespace();

const result = root.childNodes.reduce((res, node) => {
  // Get the last group (`h`, `s` or `j`)
  const previousGroup = res.slice(-1).pop();
  // Get the type and content for this node
  const { type, propertyName, content } = getProperties(node);

  // If previousGroup exists and it's of the same type
  if (previousGroup && previousGroup.t === type) {
    // Add the content to it
    previousGroup[propertyName] += content;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, create a new group
    res.push({ t: type, [propertyName]: content });
  }

  return res;
}, []);

function getProperties(node) {
  switch (node.tagName) {
    case "style":
      return { type: "s", propertyName: "s", content: node.rawText.replace(/\s+/g, " ") };
    case "script":
      return { type: "j", propertyName: "s", content: node.rawText };
    default:
      return { type: "h", propertyName: "h", content: node.innerHTML };
  }
}

console.log(result);
// Returns:
// [
//   { t: 's', s: '.myclass { padding-top: 50px; left: 0; }' },
//   { t: 'j', s: 'var name = \'world\';\n            console.log(\'Hello \' + name);' },
//   { t: 'h', h: '<div id="myid"><p class="myclass">This is a paragraph</p></div>' }
// ]
```

Comment: @Fernando Fas after posting this answer, I noticed you did not include the `maincontent` div in your example. So, do you actually not want any of the _top level_ nodes' outerHTML? Just their innerHTML? Also, if there is a `<style>` tag followed by a `<div>` and then a `<style>` again, do you want them to be grouped together, or not?

Comment: Hi blex, I just need the innerHTML. The style will always group together and will always be on the top as your amazing code, and after all the divs all grouped together. I noticed that parsing content is part of the "const root". What if I need to parse the content of an external html file targeting the body tag?

Comment: @FernandoFas Ok, I edited my answer a bit. It now uses `.querySelector('body')` to target the body inside other HTML. And it uses `innerHTML` instead of `toString`. I noticed a bug in the library, however, it keeps whitespaces in CSS. Does it fit your needs, though?

Comment: Hi bex, I can remove the whitespaces in css, but I will be happy to use your solution if you want to post it. Thank you.

Comment: I did :) I edited the answer above to reflect these changes

Comment: I'm just testing it out and cleaning up the \n and white spaces. Also, I'm trying to pull the content of an external html file. I will let you know how it goes in a bit.

Comment: Hi bex, I still can't get rid of the "\n"," \"  and whitespaces from the json file. I guess I need to work a little bit more on that. If you have time we could do this together. Also,  i use fs.writeFile with JSONstringify and the file looks good apart of the "\n", "\" and white spaces. We are getting there. I'm not an experienced nodejs dev, but as far as it goes, it's an amazing progress in this POC.

Comment: I managed to remove the `\n` and multiple whitespaces from the CSS ([See edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60225676/revisions), I added `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")` after `node.rawText`). But you don't have to remove the `\"`. They're just here so that quotes inside the string are not interpreted at the end of the string in JSON. If you read the value with JS or any other language, you won't actually see these `\\`

Comment: Morning blex, I got some improvement on the codes, but now I got in some issue about the types which is getting more complicate as I need to add the type "j" which is the javascript type. I tried to add another const type, but I'm not getting the result expected. So, when it finds the "<script>" tag, the type will change to "j".

Comment: Hello @FernandoFas I edited my answer to do this as well, using a `switch`. Note that I did not remove line breaks and spaces in JS content because it may alter the given scripts, if, for example, they use template literals with desired line breaks. But feel free to do it if that's not a problem for you

Comment: Hi blex, I made some improvements to the function and it's working fine now. Thank you for your inputs and help on this one.

Comment: Some improvements to the function:        function getTypeAndContent(node) {
switch (node.tagName) {
    case "style":return { type: 's', content: node.rawText.replace(/\s+/g, " ")
      };
    case "script":return {type: 'j', content: Buffer.from(node.rawText).toString('base64')
      };
    case "frames":return {type: 'f', content: node.rawText.replace(/\s+/g, " ")
      };
    default:return {type: 'h', content: node.innerHTML
      };
  }}
fs.writeFile('./orca/json/orca.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, '\t'), err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
})

Comment: Hey blex, I'm sorry to bother you again. I'm wondering if you could help me out with something on the functions. Do you think is possible to create a switch statement where it says: When the type = j  content type = s. So "t":"j" "s":content.

Comment: Hi @FernandoFas sure, I added a `propertyName`, so you can have one different than the `type`. Check the updated code to see if it's ok

Comment: Hey blex, that works perfectly. You are a NodeJS master.

Comment: Hi @blex, It's me again. Do you know if I can parse the data from an external file?

Comment: Hi @FernandoFas, sure, is the file on the same machine? If so, you can use `fs` to read the file. [Example here](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/gUzsBDun)

Comment: Bless you. The file is in the same machine yes and it works like a charm. Now I just have to separate all the scripts that are joined together in separate groups. I owe you a few beers.